# Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") working on touch but not with the controllers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I want to rotate an object using a Bluetooth controller in unity scene for Google cardboard. Please tell me how to make controllers work in this case.[image: This is the picture of **Fire1** button settings.]

```
 void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            transform.Rotate(transform.rotation.eulerAngles +new Vector3(0f, 0.1f, 0f));
        }
    }
```

Above is the simple code that must work when a '**Down button**' in a controller is pressed. This function is working good but only with the touch on the mobile screen **not with the controllers**.

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing type to joystick